# Run Python script from different folder: Errno 2 no file or directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, pythonpath

I am trying to use a set of Python 2.7 scripts in a folder to process some `*.csv` files in another folder on Windows 7.

Here is the folder with the scripts `C:\Users\UserH\workQ` and its contents are

```
temp_far_cels.py
convert_press.py
farrug_py33.py
site_chordelerian_asym.py
```

Unfortunately, these scripts are part of libraries and I:

1. should not be editing them; I can only use them from the command prompt.
2. should not place the `*.csv` files in the same folder as these scripts

Here is the folder with the `*.csv` files

```
C:\Users\UserH\Downloads\bu59_files
```

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#excursus-setting-environment-variables) I need to set my `PYHTONPATH`
variable. I have done this form My Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables. Here is my `PYTHONPATH` variable

```
%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\UserH\workQ
```

I have Python in my `PATH` variable as

```
....;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Currently, I am in the folder containing the `*.csv` files and I am trying to run a script from the scripts folder with this

```
C:\Users\UserH\Downloads\bu59_files> python temp_far_cels -s 'cal' -t "March 2014"
```

However, I get the following error message

```
python: can't open file 'temp_far_cels.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Is something missing here or do I need another step somewhere to run these Python scripts from any other folder in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a windows machine to test on, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work this way:

> python "C:\Users\UserH\workQ\temp_far_cels.py" (options)

I think you are over thinking this trying to work with the path files in this case.

Comment: yeah, I was trying to avoid that. But it might be my only remaining option.

Comment: Really not sure why my attempt does not work. I even tried adding the path to the scripts (`C:\Users\UserH\workQ`) to my `PATH` variable. It still did not work - I just got the very same error message `[Errno 2]`. Quite disappointing.